# how to solve for all non-negative integer xi's in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem similar to `IntegerPartitions` function, in that I want to list all non-negative integer `xi`'s such that, for a given list of integers `{c1,c2,...,cn}` and an  integer `n`:

```
x1*c1+x2*c2+...+xn*cn=n
```

Please share your thoughts. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you mean that the right hand side n is also the exact number of integers c1, c2, ..., cn? Or, can the right hand side be different, say, m? x1*c1+x2*c2+...+xn*cn == m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in function [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html) solves the case where the c1, c2, ..., cn are positive integers (and the right hand side is not n):

```
In[1]:= FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 5, 6}, 13]

Out[1]= {{0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 
  3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0, 0}}
```

Is this the case you need, or do you need negative c1, c2, ..., cn also?

Comment: great! that's what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Construct your list of `ci`'s and coefficients using

```
n = 10;
cList = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, n]
xList = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]
```

Then, if there's a set of solutions for non-negative `xi`'s, it will be found by

```
Reduce[cList.xList == n && And@@Thread[xList >= 0], xList, Integers]
```