# non-negative integer solutions to system of linear equations in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987972/how-to-solve-for-all-non-negative-integer-xis-in-mathematica), just wonder how to solve a system of linear equations with non-negative integral solutions, for example:

```
c11*x+c12*y+c13*z=d1
c21*x+c22*y+c23*z=d2
```

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**

I meant efficiently. For example, I could have used `FrobeniusSolve` to get two solution lists and try to find the intersection. But sometimes, the individual solution list is probably hugely large. Or try to verify each individual solution returned by one `FrobeniusSolve` to see whether they satisfy all the remaining equations, but that suffers from the same drawback.

Comment: The `Reduce` solution I posted last time still works...

Comment: Simon: I don't see how it works. Can you please give an example on "x1+2x2+5x3+7x4=40; x1+x2+2x3+x4=20"?

Comment: Please note I want to find all solutions, without any omission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Reduce` is able to solve these types of problems.

To answer the specific case in your comment above:

```
In[1]:= solns =  Reduce[x1 + 2 x2 + 5 x3 + 7 x4 == 40 &&
                        x1 + x2 + 2 x3 + x4 == 20 &&
                        x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0, 
                       {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers]

Out[1]= (x1 == 6 && x2 == 11 && x3 == 1 && x4 == 1) ||
        (x1 == 7 && x2 == 8 && x3 == 2 && x4 == 1) ||
        (x1 == 8 && x2 == 5 && x3 == 3 && x4 == 1) ||
        (x1 == 9 && x2 == 2 && x3 == 4 && x4 == 1) ||
        (x1 == 11 && x2 == 5 && x3 == 1 && x4 == 2) ||
        (x1 == 12 && x2 == 2 && x3 == 2 && x4 == 2)
```

---

### Edit:

You can check that this is the same solution you get by solving the two equations separately and taking the intersection of their solutions:

```
In[2]:= a = Reduce[x1 + 2 x2 + 5 x3 + 7 x4 == 40 && 
                   x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0, 
                  {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers];

        b = Reduce[x1 + x2 + 2 x3 + x4 == 20 && 
                   x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0, 
                  {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers];

In[4]:= solns == Intersection[a, b]

Out[4]= True
```

And you can extract the solutions by, e.g., 
turning the solutions into a list of replacement rules
and applying to the variables:

```
In[5]:= {x1, x2, x3, x4} /. {ToRules[solns]}

Out[5]= {{6, 11, 1, 1}, {7, 8, 2, 1}, {8, 5, 3, 1}, 
         {9, 2, 4, 1}, {11, 5, 1, 2}, {12, 2, 2, 2}}
```

Comment: +1 and you can use ToRules[] to transform the answer to a replacement list

Comment: @belisarius: can you elaborate on how to use ToRules? Ideally I want to extract the solutions as a list like {{6,11,1,1}, {7, 8, 2, 1}, ...}

Comment: also, Simon, what is your way of getting the intersection of two lists in mma?

Comment: @QiangLi - it is a built-in function http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Intersection.html

Comment: @QiangLi: See edit for use of `ToRules` and also `Intersection` acting on `Or` instead of `List`.