# **All possible** non-negative integer solutions to system of linear equations and inequalities in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integer, linear-equation

I am repeating a question ([non-negative integer solutions to system of linear equations in mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188380/non-negative-integer-solutions-to-system-of-linear-equations-in-mathematica)) here for MATLAB.

Say I have a system of linear equations and inequalities (or boundary). I want **ALL** possible non-negative integer solutions of the system. In Mathematica, the function is **reduce**. But I am not sure whether MATLAB has a similar function.

**Example**:

Problem:

```
 x1 + x3 + x4 = 3
 x2 + x3 = 3
 x1, x2, x3, x4 >= 0
```

Solution:

```
 x1   x2     x3    x4
 3     3     0     0
 2     2     1     0
 1     1     2     0
 0     0     3     0
 2     3     0     1
 1     2     1     1
 0     1     2     1
 1     3     0     2
 0     2     1     2
 0     3     0     3
```

Comment: It looks like [`intlinprog`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) in the Optimization Toolbox can do this: you can ask for integer solutions and use 0 as the lower bound.

Comment: Isn't it only providing a single solution?. I am looking for all solutions. I will edit the question with an example.